# Structure: help somebody with something

Tags: sentence-structure

> Miss Lin often helps us with our homework/English.

Can we drop “our” here?

> Miss Lin often helps us with homework/English?

Comment: It's always *possible* that "we" could be a group of trainee teachers, who sometimes need help from Miss Lin when marking their students' homework. But even then it wouldn't necessarily be "wrong" to use ***our homework*** to mean ***the homework we have to mark***.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can drop "our". Since it is reasonable that she would not help you with anyone else's homework, the meaning is the same.

Comment: But to my ear, it is much more idiomatic **with** "our".